# How do I convert a template parameter pack into multiple pointer arguments to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, variadic-templates, functor, template-meta-programming

I want to implement the following:

```
template <typename Functor, typename... Params>
void foo(
    size_t n
    /* magic goes here, producing function parameters p1, p2, etc. */
    /* corresponding to the parameter pack.                        */
)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        std::cout << Functor()( 
            /* pass p1[i], p2[i], etc. corresponding to the  */
            /* parameter pack.                               */
        )  << '\n';
    }
}
```

thus foo would expand into something like:

```
void foo(
    size_t n,
    const int* __restrict__ p1,
    const int* __restrict__ p2
)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        std::cout << std::plus()(p1[i], p2[i]) << '\n';
    }
}
```

I have a vague intuition that I might need to go beyond the standard library into something like Fusion, Brigand or Hana, which I've just started looking into; but - maybe I'm wrong and it's simpler than I think.

**Note:**

- A solution in which I pass a tuple of pointers-to-const's is acceptable, although it's sub-optimal - as I can't apply `__restrict__` to them (as it is not really C++, I know I know). Actually it's even interesting in itself since I might be able to perform other tricks with the tuple.
- I don't mind the functor taking a single tuple of pointers instead of multiple individual pointers, either.
- I'm using nvcc + GCC 5.4.1; the code should be C++11'ish (that is, the part of C++11 that I can compile as CUDA code).
- I stream the result to `std::cout` just to not give anybody the idea I'm not doing anything with the functor's return value, and this seemed the most straight-forward thing to do in example code.

Comment: `__restrict__` is not C++.  Please list your exact compiler, as no standard C++ program can contain `__restrict__`, thus your solution must be compiler-specific.

Comment: @Yakk: Fair enough; see edited notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class Functor, class...Ts>
void foo( std::size_t n,
  Ts const* __restrict__ ... ts
) {
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    std::cout << Functor{}( ts[i]...)  << '\n';
  }
}
```

well, that was easy.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ba4df3e9f142a3e).